# Cluster health - On Premise Installation

Tags: cluster-computing, azure-service-fabric

I'm testing Azure Service Fabric On Premise functionalities and I've some troubles with the cluster installed with the default configuration files provided.
As soon as some of the nodes are offline (I shutdown the host), all the cluster became unresponsive (for example : the Service Fabric Explorer became unavailable on all nodes IPs).

For example :

- If I create a 3 nodes cluster (BRONZE), all the cluster became unavailable when I shutdown one node
- If I create a 5 nodes cluster (same behavior with BRONZE and SILVER model), all the cluster became unavailable when I shutdown three nodes
- If I create a 6 nodes cluster, all the cluster became unavailable when I shutdown three nodes

I also test to disable nodes with Power-Shell after to shutdown it, but the result is the same.

I was thinking that as long as one node was still running, the cluster will be continue to work. But it seems, that the cluster became unavailable as soon as there is 50% of the nodes off, and that the cluster needs a minimum of 3 nodes to operate.

Is it the normal behavior or can I change the configuration ? How can I change it on a On-Premise installation ?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [minimum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-cluster-capacity) size of VMs for the primary node type is determined by the durability tier you choose.

The [amount](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-common-questions) of nodes you can loose is determined by quorum.

> Three nodes: with three nodes (N=3), the requirement to create a
>   quorum is still two nodes (3/2 + 1 = 2). This means that you can lose
>   an individual node and still maintain quorum

(So your remark about the 3 node cluster doesn't match with the documentation. Are you sure it really became unavailable, not just unhealthy?)

Comment: Ok, I confirm that I was wrong : for a three nodes cluster, the cluster still works with two nodes but stop to answer request when there is only one node remaining. I'm not sure to understand where I can define the "quorum". If I create a 5 nodes cluster and if I want he still answer when only two nodes are up : should I set the durability tiers to "Bronze" or to "Silver" ?

Comment: The reliability level indicates the resilience of the system services. Bronze level means '3 replica's per stateful system service'. Of those, 2 need to be healthy for your system data to be safe and redundantly stored. For your own services you can configure the replica count in the application manifest. One is fine there.

Comment: for testing you can now create a single node cluster in azure too. Check the 'single node cluster' box on 'Node type configuration'. More info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-cluster-capacity